# What are the advantages of using JSX in React?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Trying to learn React and in their official documents there's a section which says this:

*"Most React developers use a special syntax called JSX which makes it easier to write these structures."*

Then I check the given example:

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  { className: "shopping-list" },
  React.createElement(
    "h1",
    null,
    "Shopping List for ",
    props.name
  ),
  React.createElement(
    "ul",
    null,
    React.createElement(
      "li",
      null,
      "Instagram"
    ),
    React.createElement(
      "li",
      null,
      "WhatsApp"
    ),
    React.createElement(
      "li",
      null,
      "Oculus"
    )
  )
);
```

29 lines and 470 characters. How is this preferred to a plain regular HTML structure with 10 lines and 170 characters.

```
<div className="shopping-list">
  <h1>
    Shopping List for {props.name}
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Instagram</li>
    <li>WhatsApp</li>
    <li>Oculus</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSX version seems more complicated with all the commas and quotation marks. Is it just because of the html's closing tags?

Comment: Your example is not JSX but plain Javascript. Also, comparing JSX with plain HTML denotes that you actually don't understand ReactJS. JSX doesn't pretend to replace HTML but plain Javascript when developing React apps.

Comment: Huh? The first example isn't JSX. That's just JavaScript. With JSX, your HTML will be embedded within the JavaScript instead of calling methods to create the markup. I think you need to do some more basic research over what JSX is and isn't. [Wikipedia is usually a great place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#JSX) for new research.

Comment: Suggested reading https://blog.andrewray.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-jsx/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what is JSX.

From the [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html):

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

> This funny tag syntax is neither a string nor HTML...It is called JSX.

In other words, JSX is like HTML. It's easier to write code instead of pure Javascript:

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  'Hello, world!'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is code reuse. This example is a bit simple but when you face complex situations you will have opportunity to reuse code.

```
const Media = <li>{props.value}</li>;
```

As a result of this component:

```
 <div className="shopping-list">
  <h1>
    Shopping List for {props.name}
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <Media value="Instagram" />
    <Media value="WhatsApp" />
    <Media value="Oculus" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can reuse defined component.

On the other hand, in JSX you need to write HTML with javascript together. That's not desired as view and code is provided inside the same JSX file.